# Border Points in DBSCAN Demo

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I am trying to work through the application example of the [DBSCAN algorithm by scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py). Meanwhile, a few questions and thoughts arose which I'd like to address here.

The example relies on the so-called `core-samples mask`. As far as I understand it, the mask is a simple numpy array as long as the number of nodes with a negative boolean value for each. In the next step, the values in the mask array are turned to *True* at each position which DBSCAN classified as core point, while the rest remains *False*.

Later, the visualization relies on this very list. Specifically, the nodes which are *True* in both `class_member_mask & core_samples_mask` are visualized differently than the noise and border points. Here, the variable `class_member_mask` is masking each cluster (each label) the for loop is iterating over.

The second part of the visualization focuses on the `Noise`, which here are the Border Points as well as the *real* Noise points. Only the `Noise` is turned black beforehand. Correct?

To me, the distinction between Noise + Border points on the one hand, and Core points on the other hand is rather unintuitive. But that's how its done here, right?

Thanks a lot!